# How to invoke built-in commands from Visual Studio macro?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, command

From a Visual Studio macro, how do I (programmatically) invoke one of the built-in commands (say, **File.OpenFile**)?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out by recording a macro and then editing it, instead of creating it from scratch. For the benefit of others, the way to do it is (for example):

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile")
```

Comment: Would you mind commenting why that was voted down? I found the solution and shared it.